# Receiving jQuery JSON data as JSON in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I guess this is the opposite of normal case. I wish to receive the data in PHP as String with JSON in it, and I wish jQuery to Encode the data.

currently PHP decodes automatically the data to an array.

PHP 5.3.10 ( hosted ).

```
<?php
if( isset( $_REQUEST['arr']))
{
    $arr = $_REQUEST['arr'];
    $obj = $_REQUEST['obj'];   
    $res = "arr is of type ".gettype( $arr).", var_export (".var_export( $arr, true).")\n" 
         . "obj is of type ".gettype( $obj).", var_export (".var_export( $obj, true).")\n";  
    die( json_encode( $res ));
    exit;
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#csubmit").click( function() {
        var arr = new Array("one","two");
        var obj = { "one":1, "two":2 };
        var data ={ "arr" :arr, "obj" : obj };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            dataType : "json",
                complete : function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                    if( textStatus != 'success' )
                        alert("Network error ("+textStatus+"/"+jqXHR.responseText+")");
                }
        }).done( function( data ) {
            alert("Got back:("+data+")");
        });
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="submit" value="click" id="csubmit"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is always

```
Got back:(arr is of type array, var_export (array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
))
obj is of type array, var_export (array (
  'one' => '1',
  'two' => '2',
))
)
```

even though I'd like it to be a few strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are accepting back JSON, you are sending normal form-encoded data (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

```
arr%5B%5D=one&arr%5B%5D=two&obj%5Bone%5D=1&obj%5Btwo%5D=2
```

aka

```
arr[]=one&arr[]=two&obj[one]=1&obj[two]=2
```

You can confirm this from PHP by doing

```
$raw_input = file_get_contents("php://input");
echo urldecode($raw_input);
```

You are **not** sending `{"arr":["one","two"],"obj":{"one":1,"two":2}}` unless you explicitly convert in JavaScript, as the others have noted.

Comment: Good point. Seems dataType json does not make jQuery to send the arrays as JSON.

Comment: I was initially confused by that too, but ```dataType``` is what we expect back from the server.  You can send JSON in the way you'd expect by using passing the options ```data: JSON.stringify(data), processData: false, contentType : "application/json"``` to $.ajax(), but it's awkward to catch with PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your JavaScript object to JSON before sending it to server. Then you have to manually decode the json to use it as an array. In your ajax method do something like following.

```
   data : JSON.stringify(data),
```

EDIT:

JSON object is natively supported in newer browsers. For those that do not support it you can still achieve the functionality by including json2.js from http://json.org.

For more info on JSON visit https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON

Comment: In order to encode objects to JSON, you will need to donwload this API: http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 1):

Ommit the `dataType: 'json'` in an AJAX request, encode the data to a JSON within a jQuery and pass it to the PHP.

That should work.